# ADF test in R and Gretl - Why are the results different?

Tags: r, time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller, gretl

I am working on a time series-based study on the Czech Republic. I have macroeconomic data from 1993 to 2021. I tested my time series for stationarity using both R (function `adfTest` from package `fUnitRoots`) and Gretl. The results are significantly different to the point that for example the differences of GDP are strongly stationary according to Gretl, but non-stationary according to R. Both the test statistics and p-values are different. Do you have any idea why is that and which result is correct?

The test statistic for differences (I used the "constant" version and 3 lags as recommended by R)

According to R: -1.8587

According to Gretl: -4.27469

The p-values:

According to R: 0.3727

According to Gretl: 0.0004865

I am also enclosing the data

```
Year;GDP_(CZKm)
1993;1 205 330
1994;1 375 851
1995;1 596 306
1996;1 829 255
1997;1 971 024
1998;2 156 624
1999;2 252 983
2000;2 386 289
2001;2 579 126
2002;2 690 982
2003;2 823 452
2004;3 079 207
2005;3 285 601
2006;3 530 881
2007;3 859 533
2008;4 042 860
2009;3 954 320
2010;3 992 870
2011;4 062 323
2012;4 088 912
2013;4 142 811
2014;4 345 766
2015;4 625 378
2016;4 796 873
2017;5 110 743
2018;5 410 761
2019;5 791 498
2020;5 709 131
2021;6 108 717
```

Comment: Have you verified that both software platforms are working with identical versions of the data?  Often issues like this arise because something happened during a data import.  Another possibility is a misuse of a function or bug in your code.  Have you tested both systems with known data where the results have been published?

Comment: I have checked the data and they are the same. What I found is that R and Gretl estimate different models. For R, the model is lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + z.diff.lag)
and for Gretl it is (1-L)y = b0 + (a-1)*y(-1) + e (which translates to z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1). I have verified that. I think that the model definition used by R is correct based on the definition of the test. But then I don't understand why is it different in R? What purpose does it have?